# Problems creating a diet excel: create dropdown from horizontal list + update totals automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Please consider my Excel with 3 tabs: `Ingredients`, `Diet` and `Recipe`. The `Ingredients` tab lists many food types (over 120 in reality), each food type in its own column. The `Diet` tab will hold a total nutritional value for the `Recipe` created in tab 3:

Excel.Ingredients: the nutritional values are all calculated per 100 gram:

```
      A         B     C        D         E

1   Food (100g)      Milk   Weetabix   Olives
---------------------------------------------
2   Minerals   Unit
---------------------------------------------
3   calcium     mg   87       100       90
4   Iron        mg   0,05     5,16      4,66
5   Magnesium   mg   13       10        7
--------------------------------------------
6   Vitamins
--------------------------------------------
7   Vitamin C   mg   1,5      3         2,8
8   Thiamin     mg   0,04     0         0,04
9   Folate      ug   5        3         3,2
10  Vitamin D   IU   0,01     0         0
```

Excel.Diet

```
      A         B     C        D

1   Food             Goal   Amount
------------------------------------
2   Minerals   Unit
------------------------------------
3   calcium     mg   400      287    = (2 x 100) + 87
4   Iron        mg     5      10,325 = (2 x 5,16) + 0,05
5   Magnesium   mg    30      33     = (2 x 10) + 13
------------------------------------
6   Vitamins
------------------------------------
7   Vitamin C   mg   7,5      7,5    = (2 x 3) + 1,5
8   Thiamin     mg   1,5      0,04   = (2 x 0) + 0,04
9   Folate      ug   45       11     = (2 x 3) + 5
10  Vitamin D   IU   0,5      2,01   = (2 x 0) + 0,01
```

Excel.Recipe

```
      A        B    
--------------------
1   Food      Amount
--------------------
2   Weetabix  200   
3   Milk      100
```

In this example, the `Recipe` consists of 200 grams of Weetabix and 100 grams of milk. The total nutritional value for this is calculated in the `Diet` tab. Since the soure-tab for all food types (`Ingredients`) lists nutritional values per 100 gram, we have to multiply the nutritional values for weetabix by 2.

How can I:

1. Create a dropdown list in `Excel.Recipe` for all cells in column `A` containing all foods listed in the column of `Excel.Ingredients`? I have only seen examples that create a dropdown list from a vertical list of; here, the list input (the ingredients) come from a horizontal list. Or is my excel setup flawed?
2. How can I update the `Excel.Diet` whenever a value is changed or added in `Excel.Recipe`?

Answer (score 1):

Q1 is pretty straight forward. A horizontal named range is no different than a vertical named range. Create a "named range" of the row in Excel.Ingredients as follows:

```
    =OFFSET(B1,0,0,1,COUNT(IF($B$1:$ZZ$1="","",1)))
```

Where "B1" is the beginning of your Ingredients and "ZZ1" is meant to just be very large. The named range will adapt to the number of columns with entries as long as they don't go past ZZ1 or whatever you pick.

Use that named range as the "List" in your data validation drop down.

As for your Q2, I'll have to think about that. It could get pretty hairy.

Have you thought about using http://www.myfitnesspal.com/ or http://www.sparkpeople.com/?